# the clean method does not return all fields from the models

Tags: python, django

1. in the moment i have a issue related with the clean method, when i use the code line `self.cleaned_data['field']`, only show me a field-> purpose and the Process  model has more fields, i need to validate all the fields about the Process model. This is my code in the form.
2. I want that only make validations in the clean and skip the validations from models.py.

Thanks.

```
class ActivityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    role = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ActivityForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['role'].label = "Rol"

    def clean(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['purpose']
        purpose = self.cleaned_data['purpose']
        role = self.cleaned_data['role']
        order_in_structure = self.cleaned_data['order_in_structure']
        if name == '':
            raise ValidationError("Se debe diligenciar el nombre de la nueva actividad.") 

        if purpose == '':
            raise ValidationError("Se debe diligenciar la descripción de la nueva actividad.") 

        if role == '':
            raise ValidationError("Se debe dilligenciar el rol responsable de la nueva actividad.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me if works:

```
class ActivityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    role = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ActivityForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['role'].label = "Rol"

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data=super(ActivityForm, self).clean()
        name = cleaned_data['purpose']
        purpose = cleaned_data['purpose']
        role = cleaned_data['role']
        order_in_structure = cleaned_data['order_in_structure']
        if not name:
            raise ValidationError("Se debe diligenciar el nombre de la nueva actividad.") 

        if not purpose:
            raise ValidationError("Se debe diligenciar la descripción de la nueva actividad.") 

        if not role:
            raise ValidationError("Se debe dilligenciar el rol responsable de la nueva actividad.")
```

Notice that if a string is empty `not the_string` will return True